# How to put filter in left side

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.8.1. i need the layered navigation in left side but when i create the attribute, it add in toolbar.

[image]

please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Catalog -> Attributes -> Mannage Attributes

Select your attribute and then set `"Use in layered navigation"` to `"filterable with results"` and `"Use search result layered navigation"` to `Yes`.

Then check your category page layout Go to Catalog -> Manage Categories ->  Select Category -> Custom Design -> Page Layout -> Select `2 column with left` bar.

Comment: thanx for reply, i did that but still same result. layered navigation is not shown in left bar